# SignalR client method call not being recieved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr, signalr-hub

I am building a web application using AngularJS and SignalR.  To do this, I based my code off of this blog: http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com/2013/09/ABetterWayOfUsingAspNetSignalRWithAngularJs.html

I have also been using http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#logging to verify that my code is formatted correctly.  However, my code is not working correctly.

Here's some code:

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

**CarHub.cs**

```
public class CarHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string carType)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sending! - " + carType);
        Clients.All.someoneGotANewCar(carType);
    }
}
```

**Angular Service**

```
homeCarspageModule.service('signalRSvc', ["$", "$rootScope", function ($, $rootScope) {
    var proxy = null;

    var initialize = function ()
    {
        alert("Initialize!");
        //Getting the connection object 
        var connection = $.hubConnection();

        //Creating proxy 
        proxy = connection.createHubProxy('carHub');

        //Starting connection 
        connection.start();
        connection.logging = true;


        //Publishing an event when server pushes a new car
        proxy.on('someoneGotANewCar', function (carType) {
            alert("Emit! - " + carType);
            $rootScope.$emit("someoneGotANewCar", carType);
        });

        alert("Initialization Complete!");
    };

    var sendRequest = function (carType) {
        //Invoking send method defined in hub
        alert("Invoking!");
        proxy.invoke('send', carType);
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize,
        sendRequest: sendRequest
    };

}]);
```

**Angular Controller**

```
var mainCarsController = ["$scope", "$http", "$location", "$routeParams", "dataService", "signalRSvc", "$rootScope",
    function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, dataService, signalRSvc, $rootScope) {

        $scope.person = null;

        //Get car data from server
        dataService.getPersonByIdIncludeCarsAndOwners($routeParams.personId)
            .then(function(result) {
                $scope.person = result;
            }, function() {
                alert("carsController (1) : Error connecting to server");
            });

        //SignalR

        var updateOnNewCar = function (text) {
            alert("Updating!");
            alert("SignalR received: " + text);
        }

        $rootScope.$on("someoneGotANewCar", function (e, carType) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                alert("Recieved!");
                updateOnNewCar(carType);
            });
        });

        signalRSvc.initialize();

    }];
```

My code will get to the WriteLine in carhub.cs, and I get this from the logger: [image]

So I know someoneGotANewCar() has been invoked.  However, I would next expect the alert("Emit") in my service to occur on another browser, yet this does not happen.  Can someone help me find out why?

If you need more code to help find the solution just ask and I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare your proxy callback (`proxy.on(...)`) before starting the connection (`connection.start()`).

Comment: Huh.  Well then asp.net lied to me.  In my second link it specifies that you're allowed to do proxy.on() after the start method is called ["Define method on client (without the generated proxy, or when adding after calling the start method)"]

Comment: @Scott You are allowed to use porxy.on() after the start method is called. If you look at the "note" in the ["How to establish a connection" section of asp.net docs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#establishconnection), it reads in part: " If you want to register some event handlers after establishing the connection, you can do that, but you must register at least one of your event handler(s) before calling the start method... you wouldn't want to trigger the OnConnected event on every Hub if you are only going to use to one of them."